# I use Photon Pun 2 to create my game. When playing an animation, it first lags, and then begins to play normally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon-pun

I use Photon Pun 2 to create my game. When playing animation on other clients, it first lags, and then starts playing normally. At the same time, on my client the animation plays immediately smoothly. I use blend tree. Animator weighs on child object of player "Body". while the value of the horizontalInput or verticalInput variable changes from 0 to 1, the animation pauses, as soon as the value of the variables reaches 1, the animation begins to play smoothly.[PlayerSMG hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lipWx.png), [PlayerSMG inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Njh.png),  [Body inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McNfF.png), [Body animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6NrX.png), [Body blend tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQhOQ.png)

I tried to read the documentation, but I found what I needed, I will be very grateful if you can tell me how to solve this problem or provide a link to literature that will help me figure this out

`

```
public class PlayerBodyAnimationScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator playerBodyAnimator;
    private PhotonView photonView;
    void Start()
    {
        photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (!photonView.IsMine)
        {
            return;
        }

        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        playerBodyAnimator.SetFloat("Horizontal", horizontalInput);
        playerBodyAnimator.SetFloat("Vertical", verticalInput);

    }
}
```

`

Comment: [I am attaching a video of the player’s movement, where the animation lags at the beginning of the movement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1315wI9fAnHj6BGDvZ4x4i6fJUb2OfLT-/view?usp=sharing)